# Does model $R^2$ affect the interpretation of its coefficients?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, inference, r-squared

First question: is it possible for a multiple regression model to have "big" and significant coefficients but a low $R^2$ value?

Let's say the value of **$R^2$ is 0.0005** and my **coefficient of interest is 0.6**, ignoring the coefficients of all other variables I adjust for. And the dependent variable has

**range = [0,5]**

**mean = 2.5**

**variance = 4**

Second question: if that's possible, does the low  $R^2$ value affect the validity and the interpretation of my coefficient of interest?

Edit: I might be using the term validity loosely here. But my understanding is $R^2$ quantifies how much variation in the dependent variable explained by the model. So, does it make sense that I interpret the effect of the coefficient as usual (e.g. holding other things constant, 1 unit increase in my variable of interest increases the value of dependent variable by 0.6 on average) even though it explains very little of variation in the dependent variable?

Comment: To your Ist  question ; yes it is possible.  2nd question -. R-SQUARE DEPENDS ON VALIDITY. I t  is not the vice-a-versa.

Comment: I might be using the term validity loosely here. But to clear things up, because r-squared quantify explained variance of the dependent variable by the model, does it make sense that I interpret the effect of the coefficient as usual (e.g. holding other things constant, 1 unit increase in my variable of interest increases the value of dependent variable by 0.6 on average) even though it doesn't explain much of variation in the dependent variable?

Comment: even though it doesn't explain much of variation in the dependent variable? It is obscure to me

Comment: 1 unit increase in my variable of interest increases the value of dependent variable by 0.6 on average)                            It is incorrect interpretation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, it's completely possible to get large coefficients and small $R^2$ values. Consider that the coefficient values depend on units, while $R^2$ does not. So if a model with length as a predictor switches from using kilometres to millimetres, the coefficients will increase by a factor of $10^6$ without changing the $R^2$.
2. Yes, your interpretation is correct. If your coefficient is 0.6, the interpretation would be that an increase in the predictor of 1 unit is associated with an increase in the target/dependent variable of 0.6 units **on average**. This is true whatever the $R^2$ value is. But the 'on average' of course is important and it would be reasonable for the $R^2$ to affect how you interpret the coefficients, especially if you intend to use the model for prediction. So if the model $R^2$ is low, you might reduce your expectations of the predictive power of the predictor. But it would be better if you paid attention to the **standard error of the coefficient**, which measures the uncertainty in the parameter. This uncertainty is likely to be high if the model $R^2$ is low, but it's a more direct estimate of uncertainty in that specific parameter than the model $R^2$, which is a measure of the whole model.